# How do I place the argument of "min" below rather than to the side?

Tags: equations, math-operators

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{bm} 

\begin{document}


\begin{equation}
||\mathbf{x}^{1} - \bar{\mathbf{x}}^{2}|| = \textnormal {min} \limits_{\mathbf x^{2} \subseteq \Gamma^{2}} ||\mathbf{x}^{1} - \mathbf{x}^{2}({\pmb \xi)|| 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Can anyone tell me how can I bring the limits `(x^2 \subseteq \Gamma^{2}})` just below the text `min` rather than diagonally below?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `\min_{}` instead.

Comment: Replace `\textnormal {min} \limits` with `\min`.

Comment: Do you really need bold face for `\xi`? You are not using for `\Gamma`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would write `\min` instead of `\textnormal {min} \limits`, and I would use `\lVert` and `\rVert` instead of `||`.

```
\begin{equation}
\lVert \mathbf{x}^{1} - \overline{\mathbf{x}}^{2} \rVert = %
\min_{ \mathbf{x}^{2} \subseteq \Gamma^{2} } %
\lVert \mathbf{x}^{1} - \mathbf{x}^{2} ({\pmb \xi}) \rVert
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here you are: it is enough to use `\min`. I also replaced the pair of `||` with a `\norm` command, defined with the help of the `mathtools` package. The star version adds a pair of implicit `\left … \right` on both sides of the `\Vert` delimiters. If you want to fine-tune the size of the delimiters, use an optional argument instead, such as `\norm[\big]{…}` instead. You'll find details in §3.6 of the `mathtools` documentation. Btw, don't load `amsmath` if you load `mathtools`,  as the latter already does it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm\lVert\rVert

\begin{document}    \begin{equation}
  \norm*{\mathbf{x}^{1} - \bar{\mathbf{x}}^{2}} = \min_{\mathbf x^{2} \subseteq \Gamma^{2}} \norm*{\mathbf{x}^{1} - \mathbf{x}^{2}({\boldsymbol \xi)}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Sigur: I can't see where you edited it, but any way, I saw there was a problem coming from my editor, and corrected the code myself. Many thanks for pointing it!

Comment: it was number 2. http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/244940/revisions

Comment: OK. It was fine. I just can't believe I made so many typos! Sigur, are you sure you didn't add some of your own? :o)

Comment: Well, I can assume some if you wish... lol Don't worry, the problem was with a slash instead of the ` char.

Comment: Oh I see! They're next to each other on my French keyboard. I don't have that big fingers, though…